# Formatting an equation environment to fit within the margins

Tags: math-mode, margins, amsmath, amsthm

```
\mathcal{P}^s_{\delta}(F) = sup \Bigg\{ \sum_{i}|B_i|^s : 
\{B_i\} \text{is a collection of disjoint balls of radii at most 
$\delta$ with centres in F} \Bigg\}
```

This piece of text wont stay in the margins that I am writing in. I tried to put a line break, \, after the word "most" but it didnt do anything.

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've discovered, an ordinary `equation` environment won't let you insert line breaks. I suggest you load the `amsmath` package (if you're not already doing so) and use its `align*` environment to typeset the expression; insert `&` where you want the alignment points to be.

In the code below, I also make use of `\smash[b]{...}` to reduce the space between the two output lines. Incidentally, `\Bigg` would seem far too, well, big for the job at hand; I suggest using `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` to size the curly braces. Using `\colon` instead of `:` when in math mode will give you better spacing around the colon symbol. I also suggest using `\textnormal` rather than just `\text`, just in case the material occurs inside a theorem-like environment that italicizes text material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}^s_{\delta}(F) = \sup \smash[b]{\Bigl\{ \sum_{i}}|B_i|^s \colon 
&\textnormal{$\{B_i\}$ is a collection of disjoint balls}\\
&\textnormal{of radii at most $\delta$ with centres in $F$} \Bigr\} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```